# Comodo SSL - Local Network

Tags: ssl, iis

So I've set up a Comodo SSL certificate which is working fine:-

https://infinityfinance.net/

This was configured on the Windows 10 machine using IIS. This works perfect and I can see it's secure but it doesn't seem to work on the local network for some reason.

I just get a certificate warning and can't access the web site, this is when I am trying to access the web site via https://infinityfinance.net/ and not localhost, please advise.

Thanks in advance.

These are the errors when accessing locally:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the certificates you get when you connect. Because none of those really sent by the server are expired, contrary to the error message you got. The line "The certificate is only valid for ." is also suspicious. I suspect you are behing some kind of proxy that rewrites TLS exchanges. Also, this question is not related to programming.

Comment: Compare the thumbprint of the certificates in both cases. If they show different ones and you can confirm what @PatrickMevzek commented.